# JQuery '.length' property returns incorrect value when checking characters length in a div

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` with `contenteditable` attribute to make the `div` behaves like textarea.

```
<div class="caption" contenteditable>

</div>

<p id="characters-count">0 characters</p>
```

Now, I want to check how many characters in the div using JQuery `.length` property

```
$('.caption').keyup(function(){
   var char_count = $(this).text().length;
   $('#characters-count').html(char_count + " characters");   
});
```

When I type one character, it returned '11', but when there's no character, it returned '10' in Firefox. In Chrome, it is the same, but it finally correct after I press the keyboard for the second time.

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abednegosetyawan/k5B32/)

Update: I'm using Firefox 29 and Chrome 34

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just as with textareas, your div needs have no new line or spaces between the beginning and end tags.

this:

```
<div class="caption" contenteditable>

</div>
```

needs to be this:

```
<div class="caption" contenteditable></div>
```

fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k5B32/9/

Comment: i think this is the best solution because trim() could cutoff returns and actually intended white space

Comment: @Alex yeah, that's why i decided not to give a `trim()` answer ;)

Comment: use trim is the best solution always it's not

Comment: Trim won't trim carriage returns, it only trims spaces from the beginning and end. So if the user types in space space space word carriage return word space space space. Only "space" will be removed by trim

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k5B32/12/ Type in "one" then press enter, press space space space then press enter then type in another word then press enter. You'll see the count for characters will always only count actual characters and doesn't throw away the carriage return or spaces typed, unless you want a full list of any character typed included space and carriage return?

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`$.trim()`**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
var char_count = $.trim($(this).text()).length;
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/k5B32/8/

Comment: but returns will not be considered like this

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.caption').keyup(function(){
   var char_count = $.trim($(this).text()).length;
   $('#characters-count').html(char_count + " characters");   
});
```

Do this

Answer (score 0):

Your div is not empty (10 characters) because you left spaces (and spaces count)

```
<div class="caption" contenteditable></div>
<p id="characters-count">0 characters</p>**
```

see this JSFiddle :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5B32/11/)

Answer (score -2):

It's counting the spaces

```
var char_count = $(this).text().trim().length;
```

Comment: Why did somebody down vote this..? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: not sure why it was downvoted, but this would remove spaces from the div that were manually inserted by the user.

Comment: Only if the spaces occurs before or after a sentence. Not sure why it was down voted either since it does exactly what $.trim() does